# SQL result sorted twice on same column

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

How do I create a sql query that orders everything ascending that is not 0, followed by the 0's?

So the column has data like:

```
col
----
2
4
0
7
0
8
```

...and I want the query to return:

```
col
----
2
4
7
8
0
0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Order By Case When Col = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End Asc, Col Asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  SELECT ...
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN t.col = 0 THEN 999999 
           ELSE t.col
         END
```

Comment: @Nitin Midha: Correct, but it is an example